# How to download a script written for ThinkOrSwim (TOS) using curl?

Tags: curl, trading, thinkscript

The trading platform called *ThinkOrSwim* (by *[TD Ameritrade](https://www.tdameritrade.com/tools-and-platforms/thinkorswim.page)*) is using a special URL for sharing indicator scripts, directly into the trading platform. However, these scripts are just text files, and therefore you should be able to download the scripts, using *curl*. But there seem to be some kind of filter on the server side that checks *what* (or *who*) is doing the script request.

Foe example, here is a URL to a script [`http://tos.mx/A1PZUml`](http://tos.mx/A1PZUml), that is supposed to show a number of a different *Moving Averages*. For examples of actual scripts, there are plenty of them [around](https://github.com/topics/thinkorswim).

**Q: How can I directly download the TOS code using curl?**

*<sub>PS. I have added the SO tag `thinkorswim`, as the platform have it's own language called `thinkScript`, already added to SO tags.</sub>*

---

UPDATE:
From [here](https://en.opensuse.org/Thinkorswim) and looking at the contents of the files `npthinkorswim.dll` and `nptossc.dll`, it seem to be using at least 3 different custom and not [documented](https://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/media-types.xhtml) MIME types:

```
x-scheme-handler/tossc
application/x-tossc
application/x-thinkorswim
```

---

**UPDATE: 2021-04-24**

I made a little more progress [here](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/248387/how-to-intercept-application-specific-mime-types-used-by-3rd-party-windows-bro).

```js
// npthinkorswim.dll 
NoRemove MIME {
    NoRemove Database {
        NoRemove 'Content Type' {
            'application/x-thinkorswim' = s 'thinkorswim loader' {
                val Extension = s ''
                val CLSID = s '{79b4acff-94d2-58c5-baf6-23df99c7fcba}'
            }
        }
    }
}

// nptossc.dll
NoRemove MIME {
    NoRemove Database {
        NoRemove 'Content Type' {
            'application/x-tossc' = s 'thinkDesktop configuration loader' {
                val Extension = s ''
                val CLSID = s '{dcc9a6f3-492c-5f51-a65d-3dd92b26c165}'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You can supposedly run the app and have the script imported using any of these:

```sh
# To launch from anywhere (when java is installed)
javaw.exe -cp "C:\Program Files (x86)\thinkorswim\suit\1968.2.0\tos-suit-1968.2.0.jar" com.devexperts.jnlp.platform.impl.windows.WindowsSharedConfigurationLauncher SharedConfigurationLink A1PZUml

# To launch from ToS directory
.\thinkorswim.exe AutologinLink A1PZUml
.\thinkorswim.exe SharedConfigurationLink tossc:A1PZUml
```

However, this still doesn't yield any info on how to get the script using curl.

Comment: ThinkOrSwim is a trading platform, and as such, has not relationship to SO. The `thinkscript` tag is fine, as it pertains directly to coding. Anyone with knowledge of thinkScript would know that it's associated with ThinkOrSwim.

Answer (score 1):

TOS is using a custom protocol, `tossc:`, to handle shared script requests. Going to the URL you provide, `http://tos.mx/A1PZUml`, the server returns a web page containing buttons and instructions for opening the script in the TOS app.

Considering the code on that web page, clicking the *View in thinkorswim* button, say, would use the href: `tossc:A1PZUml`. That's a custom URL for opening an app with a link.

The page's JavaScript contains code to check mimetypes for the `tossc` protocol:

```
var protocol = 'tossc';
var protocolName = protocol;
for (var i = 0; i < navigator.mimeTypes.length; i++) {
    if ("tossc" == navigator.mimeTypes[i].description) {
        navigator.tosscSupported = true;
    }
}
```

I'm not a `curl` guru, but it looks like you'd have to be able to mimic the presence of the `tossc` mimetype/protocol to be able to retrieve the actual script content.

Otherwise, it looks like the server is simply responding with a way for a user to open the app using the script identifier. Once the app is opened with that identifier, I'd guess the *app* goes back to it's own servers to pull that specific script.

Comment: Yeah, I guess that's about right, but without having a good `wireshark` (*pcap*) dump of this protocol exchange it would be difficult. Probably also use a custom `user-agent` and perhaps a built-in TLS cert. I also had a brief look at the java.class files and there are several hundreds of them so it would be a real PITA to have to RE those in order to understand how they do it. I do suspect that the platform has embedded it's own access token though, that is sent with the request. At least that's what they do to use the dev branch.